# Is it possible to see wether a particular user on Instagram is publishing "promoted posts" / "boosted posts"?

Tags: instagram

Is it possible to see wether a particular user on Instagram is publishing "promoted posts" / "boosted posts" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a few key indicators for that:

1. Promoted posts usually have a 'sponsored' label which in turn signifies the user has partnered with a company or individual.
2. Most of the promoted/boosted posts either tag or thank a particular company or individual.
3. Users running promoted posts tend to add links on those posts which redirects users to other brands.
4. Users running boosted/sponsored posts tend to certain hashtags such as #ad, #sponsored &c as an indicator.